# Reversed Curly Brackets

Tags: syntax

Is it possible to turn the three centered non-numbered items in the Screenshot blew to be numbered items included in the list and replace the curly bracket on the right ?
I use `\begin{cases}` but I do not know how to achieve what I want precisely!
Here is the Screenshot.

[image]

Here is a part of my MWE:

```
\begin{enumerate}[nolistsep]
\item[15.]
$$
\begin{cases}
\text{ Before Sunrise (1995)} \\
\text{ Before Sunset (2004)}\\
\text{ Before Midnight (2013)}
\end{cases}
$$
\end{enumerate}.
```

Comment: Please see [Why is `\[` … `\]` preferable to `$$`?](http://goo.gl/GvmWy)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since you have an odd number of items you want to brace, place the construction as an in-line math equation on the middle `\item`, making room for an empty `\item` above and below:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[nolistsep,start=14]
  \item X
  \item
  \item
    \leavevmode\smash{$\left.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace\begin{tabular}{@{}l}
      Before Sunrise (1995) \\
      Before Sunset (2004) \\
      Before Midnight (2013)
    \end{tabular}\right\}$}
  \item
  \item Y
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

`\smash`ing the construction removes any vertical adjustment due to it's height.

You can also insert the right-brace as a 3-`\strut`ted `tabular` as part of the middle `\item`:

```
\begin{enumerate}[nolistsep,start=14]
  \item X
  \item Before Sunrise (1995)
  \item Before Sunset (2004) \quad
    \smash{$\left.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace\begin{tabular}{@{}l}
      \strut \\ \strut \\ \strut
    \end{tabular}\right\}$}
  \item Before Midnight (2013)
  \item Y
\end{enumerate}
```

---

If you have an even number of items, you can raise (or lower) the right brace into position:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[nolistsep,start=14]
  \item X
  \item Before Sunrise (1995)
  \item Before Sunset (2004)
  \item Before Midnight (2013)
  \item Before Noon (2018) \quad
    \raisebox{1.5\baselineskip}[0pt][0pt]{$\left.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace\begin{tabular}{@{}l}
      \strut \\ \strut \\ \strut \\ \strut
    \end{tabular}\right\}$}
  \item Y
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

---

Note that lists allow their items to break across the page boundary. So, if the latter options are chosen where the brace is `\smash`ed or raised/lowered into position, care should be taken to make sure items stay with the brace.

Answer (score 7):

I propose an *emulation* of `enumerate` based on `blkarray`:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}%
\usepackage{array, blkarray, bigstrut}

\newcounter{tabenum}
\newcommand{\tabitem}{\refstepcounter{tabenum}\makebox[\labelwidth][r]{\thetabenum.}\hspace{\labelsep}}

\begin{document}

\setlength\BAextrarowheight{4pt}
\setcounter{tabenum}{14}
\noindent\begin{blockarray}{@{}l}
\tabitem Annie Hall (1977) \\
\begin{block}{@{}l<{\,}\}}
  \tabitem Before Sunrise (1995) \\
  \tabitem Before Sunset (2004) \\
  \tabitem Before Midnight (2013) \bigstrut[b]\\
\end{block}
\tabitem Begin Again (2013)%
\end{blockarray} %

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Note that the *entire* "list" will not be breakable across the page boundary with this approach.

Comment: Yes. It's interesting only for short lists. Unless one manages to insert seamlessly a `blockarray` with braces (for which it's meaningless to break across pages) inside a `longtable` or a breakable `tabularx`.

Answer (score 5):

Using the `[resume*]` option one can break the `enumerate` into sections.  Since `enumerate` fills the full width of the text area, you need to put it inside a `minipage` and either guess or compute how wide to make it.  To compute, add the width of the widest item to `\leftmargin` (which must be saved globally from inside `enumerate`).

If you simply put the `minipage` inside `$\left. ... \right\rbrace$` the text will be pushed slightly to the right.  It is easier to measure the height using a `savebox` and use a strut.

The end result is more complicated, but at least you don't have to worry about matching the vertical spacing (except at the top and bottom of the minipage).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newsavebox{\tempbox}
\newlength{\tempwidth}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[nolistsep,start=14]
\item X
\global\tempwidth=\leftmargin
\end{enumerate}
\settowidth{\dimen1}{Before Midnight (2013)}% widest item
\addtolength{\tempwidth}{\dimen1}%
\savebox{\tempbox}{\begin{minipage}[c]{\tempwidth}
\begin{enumerate}[resume*]
\item Before Sunrise (1995)
\item Before Sunset (2004)
\item Before Midnight (2013)
\end{enumerate}
\end{minipage}}%
\vspace{2pt}% fudged
\usebox{\tempbox}$\left.\rule{0pt}{\ht\tempbox}\right\rbrace$
\begin{enumerate}[resume*]
\item Y
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

---

On second thought, just use the brace decoration from Tikz.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[nolistsep,start=14]
\item X
\item Before Sunrise (1995)
      \tikz[remember picture,overlay]{\coordinate (A) at (0pt,.6\baselineskip);}
\item Before Sunset (2004)
\item Before Midnight (2013)
      \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,decoration=brace]
        \coordinate (B) at (0pt,-.3\baselineskip);
        \coordinate (AB) at (A-|B);% when A left of B
        \draw[decorate,thick] (AB) -- (B);
      \end{tikzpicture}
\item Y
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image: tikz decoration]